# Preview freezes every time I restart it and open a file

Tags: high-sierra, preview

Every time I open a pdf or image file using Preview when Preview was not already open, Preview will freeze up for a few seconds. If Preview was already open, i.e. I already had a pdf open and opened another one, then there is no issue with opening the second pdf. I've tried resetting Preview by deleting its files in ~/Library, but the problem still persists.

Comment: how did you get the first pdf open?

Comment: maybe it was the specific pdf you tried opening?

Comment: Preview freezes for a few seconds and then unfreezes automatically. No, as I said in my question, this happens every time I open up a document in Preview when Preview wasn't already open. This issue has been ongoing for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

As a troubleshooting step I would boot your Mac into Safe Mode.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (**NOTE:** If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. use Preview a couple of times or so to test it)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Log in and test Preview again

Let me know how you go.